# blogging without having to manually upload pictures

Tags: wordpress, upload, blogging

I want to blog on a Wordpress account, without having to upload pictures manually.

I'm looking for a program that allows you to edit text + simple formatting + pictures, and lets you publish it to your blog in one step, taking care of uploading both the text and the pictures. Does anyone know of such a program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Live Writer](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1274623282&rver=5.5.4177.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http://windowslivewriter.spaces.live.com/default.aspx&id=73625&lc=1033) is one of the best blogpost composing software.

[image]

You can also use [Word 2007](http://blogmines.com/blog/2008/04/08/how-to-use-microsoft-word-2007-as-a-blog-editor-for-wordpress/).

Comment: Do Windows Live Writer and Word 2007 support Wordpress, or just Windows Live blogs?

Comment: @bguiz Windows Live Writer & Word 2007 supports any blog which provides XMLRPC api eg Windows Live, Wordpress, Blogger, LiveJournal, TypePad. I personally use Windows Live Writer to compose and post entries to my own hosted WordPress blog.

Comment: In Word, for publish to Wordpress, what is the value for `Blog Post URL`? Is `http://myblog.wordpress.com/xmlrpc.php` OK?

Comment: @bguiz - Yep that's correct!